# Get Component name in React After Webpack Minify()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to react, and just pushed our app to a live environment.  I've just encountered this error which stackoverflow doesnt seem to have a direct answer for, so i'm creating a new question for it.

I'm using ReactJS and NextJS 12.  In my `_app.js` I have an array inside `render()`:

```
let pagesThatDontNeedHeader = [
    'RegisterNow',
    'Signin',
    'LoginError',
    'CreateNewPassword',
];
let componentName = Component.name
if(componentName === 'WithRouterWrapper') {
   componentName = Component.displayName
}
```

Then below when I render the page:

```
{pagesThatDontNeedHeader.includes(componentName) ? null : <Header />}
```

So now pages like Signin, Register and Create new password dont show the header, and just the form.  Now, in production the names have all been minified and I have no way to compare and figure out whether the component needs a header or not.

What is the correct answer for this?